# Connecting VB.NET to a MySQL Database

Tags: vb.net, mysql

I have a VB.NET application and I need it to be able to display rows from a MySQL database. How would I do this?

**Update:** Another thing that I could do is have the app get a PHP page from the site that shows the DB, and gets the page every 10 seconds or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the MySQL Connector which you can get from [here](http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/).  The bottom part of [this](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/050407.htm) article describes how to install the connector and connect to the MySQL database.  [This](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql#p28) link shows some examples of connection strings.

Comment: I am not using ASP. I am using MySQL On a server and a VB.NET app on the client.

Comment: If you have a look at the example (see Step 10) you'll see that the ASP.Net code is written in VB.

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/dotnet/

That presents you with a couple of options, with connection code samples.